# Wondering - "sudo ufw app list" still show apache after removal

Tags: apache, nginx, ubuntu-16.04

I thought i had completly remove Apache from my server, until this morning where i could see, this [sudo ufw app list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cqf1T.png)

ALlready many posts here on how to remove apache etc... and everything works fine.

I'm just wondering why Apache still shown here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**sudo ufw app list** lists every app profile that you've made on the firewall. Although you uninstalled apache its profile on the firewall still exists.

If you'd like to remove it try

```
sudo rm -R /etc/ufw/applications.d/apache2*
```